# Can I split a large HAProxy config file into multiple smaller files?

Tags: haproxy

I'm building an haproxy config file that has multiple front and backends. It's going to be several hundred lines long and I'd rather split it up into separate files for each of the different websites that I want to loadbalance.

Does HAProxy offer the ability to link to partial config files from the main haproxy.cfg file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Configuration files can't be linked together from a configuration directive.

However HAProxy can load multiple configuration files from its command line, using the `-f` switch multiple times:

```
haproxy -f conf/http-defaults -f conf/http-listeners -f conf/tcp-defaults -f conf/tcp-listeners
```

If you want to be flexible with the amount of config files you can even specify a directory like this: `-f /etc/haproxy`. The files will then be used in their lexical order, newer files overriding older files.
See the [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg28891.html) for an example, if provides links to the documentation. This information can be found in the management guide, not the regular docs.

Comment: haproxy -f conf/http-defaults -f conf/http-listeners -f conf/tcp-defaults -f conf/tcp-listeners

Comment: Nice tip with the directory. I now use `-f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.d`. Additional configs can easily be added to the `haproxy.d` directory.

This is extremely useful for splitting the configuration for dataplane, so dataplane can operate on only the configuration that it needs.

Answer (score 10):

Stumbled on [this answer](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/17603) where the [author](http://search.gmane.org/?author=Michael&sort=date) created scripts to imitate nginx disable enable sites functionality. In the haproxy init.d startup he uses script loop to build the haproxy -f commands concatenation.

**/etc/init.d/haproxy:**

```
EXTRAOPTS=`for FILE in \`find /etc/haproxy/sites-enabled -type l | sort
-n\`; do CONFIGS="$CONFIGS -f $FILE"; done; echo $CONFIGS`
```

**`haensite` script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "You must be a root user" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Invalid number of arguments"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Enabling $1..."

cd /etc/haproxy/sites-enabled
ln -s ../sites-available/$1 ./

echo "To activate the new configuration, you need to run:"
echo "  /etc/init.d/haproxy restart"
```

**`hadissite` script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "You must be a root user" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Invalid number of arguments"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Disabling $1..."

rm -f /etc/haproxy/sites-enabled/$1

echo "To activate the new configuration, you need to run:"
echo "  /etc/init.d/haproxy restart"
```

Answer (score 4):

This was a solution building off of @stephenmurdoch's answer which involved the use of multiple `-f <conf file>` arguments to the `haproxy` executable.

Using the stock CentOS 6.x RPM's included `/etc/init.d/haproxy` script you can amend it like so:

```
start() {
    $exec -c -q -f $cfgfile $OPTIONS
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Errors in configuration file, check with $prog check."
        return 1
    fi

    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    # start it up here, usually something like "daemon $exec"
    #daemon $exec -D -f $cfgfile -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy_ds.cfg -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy_es.cfg -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy_stats.cfg -p $pidfile $OPTIONS
    daemon $exec -D -f $cfgfile $(for i in /etc/haproxy/haproxy_*.cfg;do echo -n "-f $i ";done) -p $pidfile $OPTIONS
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}
```

With the above in place you can then create files such as `haproxy_<X>.cfg` and `haproxy_<Y>.cfg` using whatever names you want. The above for loop will include these files in an augmented `daemon haproxy ...` line if these files are present, otherwise the stock `haproxy.cfg` file will be used solely.

Within the `haproxy_<...>.cfg` files you need to make sure that your global and defaults are defined in the "toplevel" `haproxy.cfg` file. The rest of the files simply need to have frontend/backends and nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this simple step.

1. Insert one line script (`cat /etc/$BASENAME/conf.d/*.cfg > $CFG`) in `/etc/init.d/haproxy`
   Here is position where you must insert line
   `CFG=/etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
    cat /etc/$BASENAME/conf.d/*.cfg > $CFG
    [ -f $CFG ] || exit 1`
2. Reload daemon config with `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Make directory `mkdir /etc/haproxy/conf.d`
4. Move default haproxy.cfg to conf.d as global.cfg `mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/conf.d/global.cfg`
5. Create your other .cfg file in conf.d directory
6. Just restart your haproxy service `systemctl restart haproxy`
7. NOTE: `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` will be automaticly created from all files in conf.d/

Answer (score 1):

answer of @Bapstie memtioned that, a directory can be passed to haproxy as config file, and files inside will be loaded in alphabet order. It's correct.

But problem is, the package haproxy in CentOS 'base/7/x86_64' repository is so old that it does not support that.

So either do you need to write a wrapper to append `-f <individual config file>`to the command, or you need to install latest version of haproxy:

```sh
for package in centos-release-scl-rh rh-haproxy18-haproxy; do 
    yum install -y $package
done
```

and create a drop-in config for haproxy service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-haproxy18/root/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy-nutstore/ -p /run/haproxy.pid $OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ansible you can do a trick like this:

```
- name: haproxy configuration
  copy:
    content: >
      {{ lookup('template', haproxy_cfg_src_top) +
      lookup('template', haproxy_cfg_src_edge) +
      lookup('template', haproxy_cfg_src_bottom) }}

    dest: "{{ haproxy_cfg }}"
    owner: "{{ docker_user }}"
    group: "docker"
    mode: 0664
  register: haproxy_cfg_change
```